# Primefaces 5 Mobile page prependId

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, primefaces-mobile

I'm using Primefaces 5 Mobile and trying to make a login page for spring security.
Ofcourse for this I set the form containing the username and password input fields to prependId="false".

This however did not work. After further investigation I noticed that the id of the < pm:page> tag I had wrapped everything in was prepending to child elements. Is there any way to turn this off similar to with forms(prependId="false" does not work here).

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just change request parameter names in Spring Security side instead of letting it rely on default names?

Comment: Didn't know I could do that, thanks alot it works. Please post as answer so I can accept.